# How to use group by describe with unstack operation in python dask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I am trying to use the `describe() and unstack()` function in dask to get the summary statistics of the data.

However, i get an error as shown below

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('Measurement_table.csv',assume_missing=True)
df.describe().compute() #this works but when I try to use `unstack`, i get an error
```

Actually I am trying to make the below python pandas code to work faster with the help of dask

```
df.groupby(['person_id','measurement_concept_id','visit_occurrence_id'])['value_as_number']
    .describe()
    .unstack()
    .swaplevel(0,1,axis=1)
    .reindex(df['readings'].unique(), axis=1, level=0)
```

I tried adding `compute()` to each output stage as shown below

```
df1 = df.groupby(['person_id','measurement_concept_id','visit_occurrence_id'])['value_as_number'].describe().unstack().swaplevel(0,1,axis=1).reindex(df['readings'].unique(), axis=1, level=0).compute()
```

I get the below error but the `same works well in pandas`

[image]

Can anyone help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In dask `unstack` is not implemented, but `describe` is possible use with `apply`:

```
df = (sd.groupby(['subject_id','readings'])['val']
        .apply(lambda x: x.describe())
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={'level_2':'func'})
        .compute()
        )
print (df)
    subject_id readings   func        val
0            1   READ_1  count   2.000000
1            1   READ_1   mean   6.000000
2            1   READ_1    std   1.414214
3            1   READ_1    min   5.000000
4            1   READ_1    25%   5.500000
..         ...      ...    ...        ...
51           4  READ_09    min  45.000000
52           4  READ_09    25%  45.000000
53           4  READ_09    50%  45.000000
54           4  READ_09    75%  45.000000
55           4  READ_09    max  45.000000

[112 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Can't we do this via melt in Dask?

Comment: @SSMK - Yes - https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.reshape.melt

Comment: @SSMK - I try also `pivot_table` like `df = (sd.groupby(['subject_id','readings'])['val']
        .apply(lambda x: x.describe())
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={'level_2':'func'})
        .assign(readings = lambda x: pd.Categorical(x['readings'] + '_' + x['func']))
        .pivot_table(index='subject_id', columns='readings', values='val')
        .compute()
        )` but get `NotImplementedError: Series getitem in only supported for other series objects with matching partition structure`

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your time and help.Much appreciated

Comment: I see that `dask` is also bit slow. I mean it still takes time.. Guess, I should do it in source table itself using SQL.

Comment: @SSMK - ya, if large data in pandas need a lot of RAM, so it is main reason for slowiest

Comment: Okay, you mean my system config is not good enough to process this fast. Am I right?

Comment: @SSMK - It depends of your system, but if working with large data need 32, 64GB RAM, so need run code in some server, not by NB or PC (there is obviously 4, 8, 16GB only)

Comment: Though my required output is different. But thank Jezrael for trying this. Since dask package doesn't have the unstack operation, I mark Jezrael answer as solution for his efforts. If any one could do unstack, I can modify it later.